# Graphics failure in panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, graphics, panel

I am attempting to just draw basic shapes to a panel on my form. so far nothing happens and I dont know why. This method is called in the constructor of my form.

```
private void doGraphics()
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);//draws wire frame Shapes
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);//draws filled Shapes
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();


        Point[] pointArray = { new Point(100, 20), new Point(100, 0), new Point(120, 0), new Point(120, 20) };
        g.FillPolygon(sb, pointArray);
        g.DrawPolygon(p, pointArray);
    }
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: 99% of the time calling `CreateGraphics` is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8312568/340999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register to the `Paint` event of the panel and use the graphics object that comes with the arguments:

In constructor:

```
panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
```

The handler itself:

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
{
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);//draws wire frame Shapes
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);//draws filled Shapes
        Graphics g = e.Graphics; // From Arguments


        Point[] pointArray = { new Point(100, 20), new Point(100, 0), new Point(120, 0), new Point(120, 20) };
        g.FillPolygon(sb, pointArray);
        g.DrawPolygon(p, pointArray);
}
```

Comment: and when you want to call it, do `panel1.Refresh()`

Comment: @Kyborek: `Invalidate` is normally a better choice. `Refresh` forces a redraw immediately.

Comment: @leppie whatever you want. just preventing question like "It only draws on form load, how can i redraw it?"

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method in the constructor you can not assume that the child controls and/or Graphic object are available. Use the OnPaint method of the form or create a Custom Control and override the OnPaint there.